# Customization on quick info section of sitecore item

Tags: sitecore-client

Is there any way to customize the quick info section of item like remove the template link from it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't an easy way to customize the Quick Info section of an item in Content Editor.

The code responsible to render the Quick Info section is defined in the private `RenderQuickInfo` method of the `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Editor` class. The `Editor` class cannot (and it should not) be replaced by a custom implementation.

The existing code is already not rendering the link of the template item in the Quick Info section if the current Sitecore user doesn't have the security permissions to access it. For example, a Sitecore user that has only the `sitecore\Author` role will only see the template item path value, but without a link to it.

If you are interested to display additional information for an item in Content Editor, you can implement a custom content editor warning processor and add it to the `getContentEditorWarnings` pipeline. Your custom processor should implement a `Process` method that takes the `GetContentEditorWarningsArgs` args input parameter.
For example:

```
public void Process(GetContentEditorWarningsArgs args)
{
    Item item = args.Item;
    if (item == null) return;

    // some code here to return if specific conditions are not satisfied

    // Warning initialization 
    GetContentEditorWarningsArgs.ContentEditorWarning contentEditorWarning = args.Add();
    contentEditorWarning.Title = Translate.Text("This is the warning title.");
    contentEditorWarning.Text = Translate.Text("This is the warning text.");
}
```

With this solution, your additional information will be rendered as a warning in a banner with a yellow background color. If you want, you can customize the icon of your custom warning, setting the path to your custom icon for the `Icon` property:

```
contentEditorWarning.Icon = "/path/to/your/image.png" // Default value: "/sitecore/shell/themes/standard/Images/warning_yellow.png"
```